# BASH Script passing variable with space to Heredoc?

Tags: bash, heredoc

I'm using the following:

`filename="Test File 17-07-2020.xls"`

```
sshpass -p $password ssh root@$IP /bin/bash -s "$filename" << 'EOF'

echo $1

EOF
```

This works when filename equals `Testfile.xls` and the echo outputs the full filename.

But fails if the filename is called `Test File 17-07-2020.xls`

My understanding is the spaces are breaking the input so it becomes:

```
$1 = Test
$2 = File
$3 = 17-07-2020.xls
```

Is there anyway to pass this keeping the spaces and having it all in `$1`

If I add `filename=$(echo "$filename" | sed 's/ /\\ /g')` before the SSHPASS command it does work.

Is that a valid way to do it or is there a better way ?

Thanks

Comment: echo "$1" shows 'Test' not the full name.

Comment: As a poor substitute in cases where you don't need that second argument you could maybe use `"$*"` instead of `$1`, but it isn't a very robust solution.

Answer (score 1):

You still need to quote `$1`. Quoting the delimiter prevents `$1` from being expanded early; it doesn't prevent word splitting once the shell actually executes `echo $1`.

```
sshpass -p $password ssh root@$IP "/bin/bash -s \"$filename\"" << 'EOF'

echo "$1"

EOF
```

If you are using `bash` locally, there are two extensions that could produce a value that is safe to pass to the remote shell.

```
sshpass -p $password ssh root@$IP "/bin/bash -s $(printf '%q' "$filename")"
```

or

```
sshpass -p $password ssh root@$IP "/bin/bash -s ${filename@Q}"
```

The former works at least in `bash` 3.2 (I highly doubt you are using an older version), while the latter requires `bash` 4.4.

Comment: I've found this, but if the filename has spaces without the slashes then $1 only contains Test.

Comment: Oh, right, because the entire set of arguments is packaged as a single word by `ssh` to pass to the remote shell. I've fixed it to handle your case, but this still isn't robust: it will fail if `$filename` contains a double-quote itself.

Comment: You could swap the inner double quotes for single quotes (`"/bin/bash -s '$filename'")`, but that just shifts the problem to filenames containing single quotes.

Comment: How about `${filename@Q}`?

Comment: Yeah, I was just playing around with that. `printf '%q' "$filename"` and `"${filename@Q}"` produce different output, so I was trying to convince myself either would work. (I might lean towards `print "%q" ...` as being more likely to be supported; `@Q` requires `bash` 4.4 or later.